# Renaming localstorage in browser

Tags: local-storage

I have an application that uses localstorage and has some information tied to the site that is serving the content. We'd like to change the site name and was wondering if there is a way we can rename the localstorage associated with a domain, (both in chrome and firefox).

e.g. Rename the localstorage from x.company.com to y.company.com

Answer (score 1):

Not possible due to security restrictions in Chome / FF.